# $D_{12}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3\times D_4.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

> Prove/Disprove:
>
> $D_{12}$ is isomorphic to  $\Bbb Z_3\oplus D_4.$

$D_{12}$ has 11 elements of order $12$ whereas $\Bbb Z_3\oplus D_4$ has 9 elements of order $12$ since $\Bbb Z_3$ has $3$ elements of order $3$ and $D_4$ has $3$  elements of order $4$.

So they are not isomorphic.

Is this true?

Comment: Why "sub"group in your title ?

Comment: Your counting is very bad! They both have $4$ elements of order $12$, so that does not work, but they have different numbers of elements of order $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to check whether $D_{12}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus D_4$ or not. The answer is no. Explanation:

Each group has $4$ elements of order $12$, $2$ elements of order $4$ and $2$ elements of order $3$. But $D_{12}$ has only $2$ elements of order $6$ whereas $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus D_4$ has $10$ elements of order $6$.

Further, $D_{12}$ has $13$ elements of order $2$ while $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus D_4$ has $5$ elements of order $2$.

You can verify this by counting number of rotations & reflections in $D_{12}$, and by taking l.c.m of orders in $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus D_4$.

Comment: how does $D_{12}$ have 4 elements of order $12$

Comment: $D_{12}$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $C_12$, the cyclic group of order 12. This subgroup has $4$ generators.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check whether $D_{12}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus D_4$ or not. The answer is no. Explanation:

Each group has $4$ elements of order $12$, $2$ elements of order $4$ and $2$ elements of order $3$. But $D_{12}$ has only $2$ elements of order $6$ whereas $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus D_4$ has $10$ elements of order $6$.

Further, $D_{12}$ has $13$ elements of order $2$ while $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus D_4$ has $5$ elements of order $2$.

You can verify this by counting the number of rotations & reflections in $D_{12}$, and by taking l.c.m of orders in $\mathbb{Z}_3 \oplus D_4$.

$D_{12}$ has a unique cyclic subgroup of order $12$ which is generated by rotation. Every cyclic group of order $n$ has $\phi(n)$ generators. Here $n =12$ and $\phi(12)=4$. To better understand $D_n$, try $D_3$ or $D_4$ or both.

Comment: You have posted two duplicate answers.